# Term name of current node in title

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to echo out the current term name that my node is inside of into my function, but it only keeps echoing out 1 and not the name. This is what I have.

```
function bartik_process_html(&$variables) {
  // Hook into color.module.
  if (module_exists('color')) {
    _color_html_alter($variables);

    if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
      $variables['head_title'] = implode(' - ', $variables['head_title_array']);
    }
    elseif (node_is_page()) {
      $terms_name = print $term_name->name;
      $variables['head_title'] = implode(' - '.$terms_name.' - ', $variables['head_title_array']);
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is using the following line:

```
$terms_name = print $term_name->name;
```

You are assigning to `$terms_name` the value returned by `print $term_name->name`, which is 1.
If you try executing `$var = print "ciao";`, you will notice that the value assigned to `$var` is 1.

The other issue with that code is that `$term_name` is not a variable defined from the code you showed; executing that code, you get an "access to a not defined variable" error.

Comment: Ok I understand what your telling me about what im doing wrong so how can I fix this problem?

Comment: take out the print() function. so... $terms_name = $term_name->name; or if you just want to print it, print($term_name->name);